# Remove the scripts created by page loaded in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading a page(child.html) inside a div using .load() method in my main page(parent.html) . The child also contains a script  which is same as the script included in parent page . I am making an AJAX request from the child.html page to submit a form . After the form is submitted , I am removing the div containing child.html from the DOM . Now when I am trying to call a function by clicking on a button from the parent.html page , the function is called on a different source . When I opened debugger on chrome to check if the correct function was called , I found that the debugger has opened the function in a new source tab (with a yellow background) instead of calling the function in the main source file . I want to understand what is happening .

To load content into div

```
    $modal = jQuery('<div class="modalDialog" url='+url+' uri='+uri+'></div>');
    $content = jQuery('<div class="contentDialog"></div>');
    $close = jQuery('<a class="closeModalDialog" href="#" data="cross">close</a>');
    $loadingMessage = jQuery('<p class="loadingMessage">Loading ....</p>');
    $content.load( url, function( response, status, xhr ) {});
```

To remove the div

```
    jQuery(jQuery('.contentDialog')[0]).empty();
    jQuery(".modalDialog")[0].remove();
    jQuery(".overlayModalDialog")[0].remove();
```

This is the function which is called from the parent page

```
    a href="#" onclick="DisplayIteratorPage()
```

Comment: put your surch code here for batter understood.